# How to locate the position of an underscore in a string (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

1. I'm trying to return a column that identifies the position an underscore (_) is located.

Example Data: STRING1_STRING2

For example, if I use the LENGTH function I can return the length of the string:

SELECT LENGTH(COLUMN1)

returns - 15

But I want to find the length / position of the underscore (_) in my string. I'm trying, SELECT INSTR('_', COLUMN1). All this returns is 0 for all rows...

Using the above example data, I'm expecting 8 to be my result.

2. The reason to identify the length/position of the underscore (*) is to use this in the SUBSTR function to delimit the string from the 1st underscore (*), For example:

SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN1, 1, /*POSITION OF UNDESCORE*/ -1)

Should return - STRING1

INSTR('_', COLUMN1) doesn't seem to find the underscore. How do I escape the underscore properly in the select statement?

Do I need a different function to achieve my result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have swapped the order of input parameters to `INSTR()`, which expects the string to be searched first, and the substring second.  Use this version and it should work:

```sql
SELECT COLUMN1, INSTR(COLUMN1, '_') AS pos
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you, That worked a treat! Can't believe I had it the wrong way around!